# Help with typing on a circular line and then stacking

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

Is there a better way to stack circular lines of type under (or above) a circular graphic, than creating individual "type on a line" lines? It is difficult to manage to get the curving text lines to line up exactly even, especially if the copy on each line is different lengths. It looks messy.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, this is your problem:

[image]

This 'messy' effect is due to the fact that the text paths have exactly the same shape: a (part) cirle with a fixed radius. In order to have the type line up neatly, you'll have to use multiple concentric circles of varying radius:

[image]

You can easily create concentric cirles like these by drawing the first one and then choosing <kbd>Object > Path > Offset Path...</kbd> with a constant value.

Adding type to the concentric paths yields this effect:

[image]

Which lines up way better and is easier on the eyes.

If you don't want to center your text but left- or right-align it, it might help to line up the starting points of each line:

1. draw a line perpendicular to the text paths;
2. <kbd>right click</kbd> > <kbd>Make Guides</kbd>;
3. with the direct selection / white arrow tool (<kbd>A</kbd>) active, click on the type (not the path itself!) to render visible the type location anchors;
4. drag the starting anchor on top the guide;
5. repeat steps 3 and 4 for the other lines.

[image]